# How do I get my NSTextView to respond properly to the Home and End keys?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

Apple makes `NSTextView` respond to page up, page down, arrow keys, etc. automatically, but the home and end keys are not automatically handled by `NSTextView` out of the box.  There's no apparent reason for this; I just logged a Radar on it.  Until they fix that Radar, the question is: how do I make my `NSTextView` handle those keys correctly?

I just spent a little while googling around about this, and didn't find a good modern answer on either SO or elsewhere, so I'm posting my own answer here just for other's reference.

Comment: What makes you think that `NSTextView` doesn't implement `-scrollToBeginningOfDocument:`? It does in my version of AppKit (El Capitan). It seems pretty similar to your implementation.

Comment: Well, I'm on 10.11.3, and my NSTextView doesn't respond to the home or end keys.  When I added the code given in my answer, it then did respond to the home and end keys.  I'm not sure what else could be going on...

Comment: Have you tried with a new, simple project? I just did and Home and End work fine. From the code, it seems that `NSTextView` is looking up the `textStorage` and, if it's `nil`, it does nothing. Did you build the text system programmatically such that something may be off?

Comment: Hmm, very odd.  This is in a relatively complex project, with a custom subclass of `NSTextView` and a custom `NSTextStorage` subclass as well.  But everything about the app works well except that Home and End didn't work properly; certainly the text storage is not nil.  I'll take your word for it that a vanilla project with a vanilla `NSTextView` works.  Nevertheless, the fact remains that in some circumstances Apple's Home/End handling apparently fails, and the answer below fixes the problem.  I have no idea why, and without access to Apple's code, no way to figure out why.  I logged a Radar.

Comment: `NSTextView`'s implementation also does nothing if the `textStorage`'s `length` is zero. Anyway, I guess you've got a solution that works for you. Good luck isolating it further and/or getting a fix from Apple.

Comment: Yes, my text storage is also not length zero.  :->  Thanks.  And thanks for the information that NSTextView does do this correctly "out of the box" – that's interesting, and will go into my Radar report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **wrong** way to do this is to implement `keyDown:` and check for the particular keys having been pressed.  This circumvents Apple's key-binding mechanism, which as it happens does supply the needed selectors for the concepts of "scroll to beginning" and "scroll to end"; `NSTextView` just doesn't respond to those selectors.

All you need to do is to add, in your NSTextView subclass, the following:

```
- (void)scrollToBeginningOfDocument:(id)sender
{
    [self scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}
- (void)scrollToEndOfDocument:(id)sender
{
    [self scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[self string] length], 0)];
}
```

This hooks up the NSResponder methods for the relevant key bindings to appropriate actions in your NSTextView.  These methods on NSResponder appear to have been public since 10.6 or so, and may have actually existed for a while before that, so this solution should be good on all modern systems.